# How to adjust the formatting of variable number of arguments?

Tags: python, string, formatting

With this list as an input :

```
my_list = [
    ['a', 'b'],
    ['c', 'd', 'e'],
    ['f', 'g'],
    ['h']
]
```

I'm trying to print adjusted to the left strings but there are missing values :

```
for i in my_list:
    print('{:<10}'.format(*i))
  
a         
c         
f         
h
```

Why `format` isn't capable of deducting the length of each nested list ?

My expected output :

```
a          b       
c          d          e
f          g
h
```

I'm looking for a robust solution with `{:<10}` syntax rather than this :

```
for i in my_list:
    print(*i, sep=' '*10)
```

Comment: "Why format isn't capable of deducting the length of each nested list ?" Because you passed multiple values to the `format` method, but that string only has one **placeholder**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply `'{:<10}'.format` to each element:

```
for i in my_list:
    print(*map('{:<10}'.format, i))
```

Output:

```
a          b         
c          d          e         
f          g         
h
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `*` operator to multiply the formatting string:

```py
my_list = [["a", "b"], ["c", "d", "e"], ["f", "g"], ["h"]]

for t in my_list:
    print(("{:<10}" * len(t)).format(*t))
```

Prints:

```
a         b         
c         d         e         
f         g         
h
```